# Как мне сделать так, чтобы вывелось конкретное значение между двумя

Tags: sql, oracle

Ситуация такая, у меня есть столбец, который я получил в результате расчета, в это столбце 2 значения, они могут быть как '?' и '?', так и '?' и 'значение'
Мне нужно написать расчет, чтобы если у меня '?' и 'значение', то он выбирал значение а если заполненного значения нет ('?' и '?') то выбирал одно  из '?' и '?'
условие в том, что 'значение' может быть разным
то есть '?' и 'fgdg'
'?' и 'erwe'
'?' и 'yury' и мне нужно чтобы он выбирал именно заполненное, не ссылаясь на название этого значения
Господи, надеюсь понятно, потому что я сам запутался уже
знак '?' это типа не заполненное

Comment: *условие в том, что 'значение' может быть разным то есть '?' и 'fgdg' '?' и 'erwe'* А как отличать, является `'?'` значением или нет? будет лучше, если показать *столбец, который я получил в результате расчета* в виде готового CTE плюс требуемый для него результат с пояснениями.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типа такого, хотя я точно синтаксис не помню и в `Oracle` может отличаться:

```sql
select 
    case when col1='?' then 1 else 0 end,
    col1,
    col2,
    col3 
from data
order by 1
limit 1
```

Суть в том, чтобы отсортировать записи в таком порядке, чтобы вопросики шли заведомо позже других значений, ну и выбрать после этого первую запись.

Comment: ```ORDER BY NULLIF(col1, '?') NULLS LAST```

Comment: Слушай, я тут кое что узнал, если будет два одинаковых '?' и '?', или две строчки с двумя значениями, то он должен вообще не выводить строчки, такое возможно сделать? 
 то есть если ?? или  значение значение  то пустая таблица

Answer (score 1):

> '?' это типа не заполненное

если вы так обозначили `null`, то всё просто:

```
select max(col1), max(col2) from your_table
```